# Error in nimbus log

Tags: apache-storm

When I tried to run a topology in my storm client I got an error that point to a connection failed with the nimbus . 
I checked my numbus log and here's what shows :

```
2014-04-25 11:05:03 nimbus [INFO] Uploading file from client to storm-local/nimbus/inbox/stormjar-7106a3e1-fae8-4afe-8028-5c561eeb365e.jar
2014-04-25 11:05:03 nimbus [INFO] Finished uploading file from client: storm-local/nimbus/inbox/stormjar-7106a3e1-fae8-4afe-8028-5c561eeb365e.jar
2014-04-25 11:05:03 nimbus [INFO] Received topology submission for beat with conf {"topology.max.task.parallelism" nil, "topology.acker.executors" 1, "topology.kryo.register" nil, "topology.kryo.decorators" (), "topology.nam$
2014-04-25 11:05:03 nimbus [INFO] Activating beat: beat-2-1398416703
2014-04-25 11:05:03 EvenScheduler [INFO] Available slots: (["c3a1bab3-ed50-4efc-b424-050d34d7d4bd" 6702] ["c3a1bab3-ed50-4efc-b424-050d34d7d4bd" 6703] ["8f506a92-4a1b-4cc6-8f80-ed53ea810256" 6701] ["8f506a92-4a1b-4cc6-8f80-e$
2014-04-25 11:05:03 nimbus [INFO] Setting new assignment for topology id beat-2-1398416703: #backtype.storm.daemon.common.Assignment{:master-code-dir "storm-local/nimbus/stormdist/beat-2-1398416703", :node->host {"c3a1bab3-e$
2014-04-25 12:08:03 nimbus [INFO] Cleaning inbox ... deleted: stormjar-7106a3e1-fae8-4afe-8028-5c561eeb365e.jar

**2014-04-25 13:59:47 TNonblockingServer [ERROR] Read an invalid frame size of -720899. Are you using TFramedTransport on the client side?
2014-04-25 14:00:16 TNonblockingServer [ERROR] Read an invalid frame size of -720899. Are you using TFramedTransport on the client side?**
```

any clarification  ?

Comment: the problem was that the file I wanted to read was in a read-mode by another  token .